# Adding Image In JFrame : Java

Tags: java, jframe, panel

If I Use This Way To Add image in panel

```
static ImageIcon bg = new ImageIcon("hangman1.png");
```

Then Where Should Be Mine hangman1.png should be so it display correctly??

Comment: Are you adding image as a background of JFrame or what?

Comment: I Am adding it to JLabel So I Can Show It On The Front End

Comment: And where is your hangman1.png file? In some java package within of your project or on file system?

Comment: Its In My System "Lets Say on My Desktop ", And I Am Unable To LInk It With My Label

Answer (score 1):

Load your "hangman1.png" file as a resource and add it to `JLabel`:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/path/to/your/image/hangman1.png")));
```

Before of that, add it into some package in your Java project.